# Grails cucumber and Geb - running tests in firefox and cucumber approach

Tags: selenium, grails, groovy, geb, cucumber-jvm

I have used this as a guide with cucumber and how to use Geb [Github hauner grails-cucmber example](https://github.com/hauner/grails-cucumber/wiki/Testing-Grails-with-Cucumber-and-Geb)

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, I've used Geb in the past...

Tests would be run from a *[some name here]Spec.groovy* that would extend GebReportingSpec.... Using the Geb page model

Instead tests are run from a StepDef via cucumber... which I'm not quite sure, how to integrate the screenshots, I suppose you're to do it manually :/

I'm unable to get this working under Windows 7, using Firefox version 39, 40, 41, 42. I've managed with others even IE! I've not been able to check under Linux. The end goal will be to use a selenium grid. Both being able to run local and remote.

**BuildConfig.groovy**

```
def gebVersion      = "0.12.2"
def seleniumVersion = "2.48.2" //2.45.0
def cucumberVersion = "1.2.0"

repositories {
    ... (snippet)

    mavenRepo "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" //Geb snapshot
}

dependencies {
     test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"

    // Geb / Spock  // http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#grails
    test "org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:$seleniumVersion" //Needed by phantomjsdriver
    test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0"
    test("com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.2.1") {
        transitive = false // phantomjs driver pulls in a different selenium version
    }
}

plugins {
    test ":geb:$gebVersion"
    test ":cucumber:$cucumberVersion 
}
```

**CucumberConfig.groovy**

```
cucumber {
    features = ["test/functional/cucumber/features"]
    glue     = ["test/functional/cucumber/steps", test/functional/cucumber/hooks", "test/functional/cucumber/support"]
    tags     = ["~@ignore"]
}
```

**support/env.groovy**

```
def bindingUpdater
def activeBrowser

Before { scenario ->
    activeBrowser  = new Browser()
    bindingUpdater = new BindingUpdater(binding, activeBrowser)
    bindingUpdater.initialize()
}

After { scenario ->
    bindingUpdater?.remove()
}
```

**Example snippet of compiled Gherkin feature**

```
Given(~/^User goes to SomePage$/) { ->
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    to SomePage
    at SomePage
}
```

(p.s. on a side note intellij doesn't pick up the fact that Geb exists here in case anyone else has had this issue)

**EDIT** - Included **GebConfig**

```
baseNavigatorWaiting = true
atCheckWaiting       = true
reportsDir           = "target/geb-reports"

driver = {
    System.setProperty('webdriver.firefox.bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox 41\\firefox.exe')

   //http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy
   org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy([autodetect:true]);

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

    def driverInstance = new FirefoxDriver(cap)
    driverInstance.manage().window().maximize()
    driverInstance
}

...(snipped other enviroments/functionality)
```

Answer (score 2):

Grails 2.x (as far as i know) does not support to add screenshots to the test report.

I did a quick test and I found 2 possibilities to get screenshots. I tested both with the [geb sample](https://github.com/hauner/grails-cucumber/tree/master/test/projects/Books_geb) of the plugin:

### cucumber html report

**CucumberConfig.groovy**

```
cucumber {
    // the other settings
    plugins = ["html:target/results"]
}
```

Adding this will tell cucumber to create a html report in `target/results`.
To add a screenshot to the report you create it in the `After` hook and add it to the report:

**env.groovy**

```
import cucumber.api.Scenario
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType

After () { Scenario scenario ->
    def screenshot = browser.getDriver().getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES)
    scenario.embed(screenshot, 'image/png')

    bindingUpdater.remove ()
}
```

This will create a test report including screenshots.

### geb report

It is possible to call the `browser` object from a step:

```
Given(~/^User goes to SomePage$/) { ->
    to SomePage
    at SomePage
    browser.report('SomePage')
}
```

The html/screenshot will be written to `target/test-reports/geb`.

The `After` hook will work too:

```
After () { Scenario scenario ->
   browser.report(scenario.name)

   bindingUpdater.remove ()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will have a try of this, it doesn't appear to even generate the report specifically for Geb... which is the strange part. 

Do you have any idea of why I'm experiencing issues launching Firefox (I will update with GebConfig snippet, too big to include for each of the other browsers), see question for versions tried)